# The register button doesn't do anything

Tags: html

My submit button does not do anything...

I've seen multiple posts on stackoverflow regarding similar issues, mostly due to not using  around the code, etc.

```
<from action="" method="post">
<ul>
    <li>
        Username*:<br>
        <input type="text" name="username">
    </li>
    <li>
        Password*:<br>
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </li>
    <li>
        Confirm Password*:<br>
        <input type="password" name="password_again">
    </li>
    <li>
        First Name*:<br>
        <input type="text" name="first_name">
    </li>
    <li>
        Last Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="last_name">
    </li>
    <li>
        Email Address*:<br>
        <input type="text" name="email">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Register">
    </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Your `form` element is spelt `from`

Comment: Thanks you Andy, being dyslexic can be a nightmare...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake. You spelled form as "from" and that's why you form didn't submit. Here is the corrected code:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Username*:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username">
        </li>
        <li>
            Password*:<br>
            <input type="password" name="password">
        </li>
        <li>
            Confirm Password*:<br>
            <input type="password" name="password_again">
        </li>
        <li>
            First Name*:<br>
            <input type="text" name="first_name">
        </li>
        <li>
            Last Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="last_name">
        </li>
        <li>
            Email Address*:<br>
            <input type="text" name="email">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Register">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```